# PROBLEMA JUEGO BLACKJACK PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito ayuda con un problema que me ha surgido, estoy diseñando un juego de BlackJack y tengo un problema con la actualización de un frame de **Tkinter**.
El programa, cuando es ejecutado, crea una nueva ventana que es la interfaz para jugar, y se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy empezando a configurar el juego y estoy programando la función que se ejecuta cuando presiono el botón de **"Bet $5"**. El problema es que en la función que se ejecuta cuando lo presiono se actualizan dos variables:

- La variable **"My_money_variable"** que almacena el valor del dinero que posee el jugador
- La variable **"the_pot_value"** que almacena el valor del dinero que se está apostando

Lo he estado comprobando y es cierto que esos valores, declarados como variables globales, se llegan a actualizar. El problema es que en la interfaz de la imagen anterior, el valor de "My money" (que en este caso se puede ver que es 90$) no se actualiza, y el valor de "The Pot" (que en este caso es 0$") tampoco se llega a actualizar. No se qué problema existe con el código. A continución lo comparto y sería de enorme ayuda si alguien pudiese echarme un cable.

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import os
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self,numero):
        self.numero = numero
        

    def isFaceDown(self):
        if self.descubierta == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def setFaceDown(self):
        self.descubierta = False

        
    def setFaceUp(self):
        self.descubierta = False
        
    def getBlackJackRank(self):
        if ((self.numero == 11) or (self.numero == 12) or (self.numero == 13) or (self.numero == 24) or (self.numero == 25) or (self.numero == 26) or (self.numero == 37) or (self.numero == 38) or (self.numero == 39) or (self.numero == 50) or (self.numero == 51) or (self.numero == 52)):
            return 10
        if ((self.numero == 2) or (self.numero == 15) or (self.numero == 28) or (self.numero == 41)):
            return 2
        if ((self.numero == 3) or (self.numero == 16) or (self.numero == 29) or (self.numero == 42)):
            return 3
        if ((self.numero == 4) or (self.numero == 17) or (self.numero == 30) or (self.numero == 43)):
            return 4
        if ((self.numero == 5) or (self.numero == 18) or (self.numero == 31) or (self.numero == 44)):
            return 5
        if ((self.numero == 6) or (self.numero == 19) or (self.numero == 32) or (self.numero == 45)):
            return 6
        if ((self.numero == 7) or (self.numero == 20) or (self.numero == 33) or (self.numero == 46)):
            return 7
        if ((self.numero == 8) or (self.numero == 21) or (self.numero == 34) or (self.numero == 47)):
            return 8
        if ((self.numero == 9) or (self.numero == 22) or (self.numero == 35) or (self.numero == 48)):
            return 9
        if ((self.numero == 10) or (self.numero == 23) or (self.numero == 36) or (self.numero == 49)):
            return  10
        if ((self.numero == 1) or (self.numero == 14) or (self.numero == 27) or (self.numero == 40)):
            return 1
     
def main():
    i = 0
    def Hit():
        global numero_de_carta_del_jugador
        numero_de_carta_del_jugador = numero_de_carta_del_jugador + 1
        carta_siguiente = random.choice(List_of_cards)
        imagen_siguiente_carta_jugador = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file=(str(carta_siguiente) + ".png"))).subsample(3)
        List_of_cards.remove(carta_siguiente)
        valor_que_tiene_el_jugador = valor_que_tiene_el_jugador + int(Card.getBlackJackRank(carta_siguiente))
    def Stand():
        i = 0
    def Bet_5():
        global My_money_variable
        global the_pot_value
        
        if My_money_variable < 5:
            print("No funds")
        else:
            My_money_variable = My_money_variable - 5
            the_pot_value = the_pot_value + 5
        
    def Bet_10():
        global My_money_variable
        global the_pot_value
        if My_money_variable < 10:
            print("No funds")        
        else:
            My_money_variable = My_money_variable - 10              
            the_pot_value = the_pot_value + 10
            
    #defino la interfaz abajo
    
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    
    root.title("Black Jack")
    root.resizable(width=True,height=True)
    bar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    
    fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(bar,tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.quit)
    bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fileMenu)
    root.config(menu=bar)
    
    cardsFrame = tkinter.Frame(root,borderwidth=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    cardsFrame.pack()
    
    entryFrame = tkinter.Frame(cardsFrame)
    entryFrame.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    
    zona_Cartas = tkinter.Frame(cardsFrame)
    zona_Cartas.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Hit", command=Hit).grid( row =0 , column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Stand", command=Stand).grid( row =1 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Bet $5", command=Bet_5).grid( row =2 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Bet $10", command=Bet_10).grid( row =3 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)    
    
    My_money_Label = tkinter . Label (entryFrame, text ="My Money")
    My_money_Label . grid ( row =4 , column =0 )
    
    
    
    My_money_value = tkinter . Label (entryFrame, text = str(My_money_variable) + "$")
    My_money_value . grid ( row =4 , column =1 )    
    
    
    The_Pot_Label = tkinter . Label (entryFrame , text ="The Pot")
    The_Pot_Label . grid ( row =5 , column =0)
    
    The_Pot_value = tkinter . Label (entryFrame , text = str(the_pot_value) + "$" )
    The_Pot_value . grid ( row =5 , column =1 )    
    
    Card_Totals_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Card Totals")
    Card_Totals_Label . grid ( row =6 , column =0 , columnspan = 2)
    
    Player_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Player")
    Player_Label . grid ( row =7 , column =0 )
    

    Player_value = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame)
    Player_value . grid ( row =7 , column =1 )    
    
    Dealer_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Dealer")
    Dealer_Label . grid ( row =8 , column =0 )
    
    Dealer_value = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame)
    Dealer_value . grid ( row =8 , column =1 )    
    
    List_of_cards = list(range(1,52))
    
    #reparto las dos cartas al jugador
    carta_1_jugador = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_1_jugador)
    carta_2_jugador = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_2_jugador)
    #reparto las dos cartas al dealer
    carta_1_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_1_dealer)
    carta_2_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_2_dealer) 
    
    #inserto las imagenes de las cartas
    
    imagen_carta_1_jugador = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
    imagen_carta_2_jugador = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
    imagen_carta_1_dealer = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
    imagen_carta_2_dealer = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
    
    imagen_carta_a_repartir = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png").subsample(3)
    
    label_imagen_carta_1_jugador = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_1_jugador)
    label_imagen_carta_1_jugador.grid(row =2, column = 0)
    
    label_imagen_carta_2_jugador = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_2_jugador)
    label_imagen_carta_2_jugador.grid(row =2, column = 1)
    
    label_imagen_carta_1_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_1_dealer)
    label_imagen_carta_1_dealer.grid(row =0, column = 0)
    
    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_2_dealer)
    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.grid(row =0, column = 1)   
    

    label_imagen_carta_a_repartir = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_a_repartir)
    label_imagen_carta_a_repartir.grid(row =1, column = 0)    
    
    
    
    carta_1_jugador = Card(carta_1_jugador)
    carta_2_jugador = Card(carta_2_jugador)
    carta_1_dealer = Card(carta_1_dealer)
    carta_2_dealer = Card(carta_2_dealer)
    
    valor_que_tiene_el_jugador = carta_1_jugador.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_jugador.getBlackJackRank()
    valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank()
    
    
#defino la interfaz arriba
    
    
    
    
    def appClosing():
        
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
        sys.exit()    
    
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", appClosing)  
    
         
    tkinter.mainloop()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numero_de_carta_del_jugador = 3
    numero_de_carta_del_dealer = 3
    the_pot_value = 0
    My_money_variable = float(input("Please enter the money you want to start with: "))
    main()
```

Pego todo el código para que puedan entender el contexto, pero lo importante es la función **Bet_5()** que es la que rige el funcionamiento cuando selecciono el botón **"Bet $5"**

Sería de enorme ayuda si pudieseis ayudarme a encontrar por qué no se actualiza en la ventana.

Comment: Te falta actualizar la interfaz. Actualmente sólo estás actualizando las variables pero no actualizas los labels de la interfaz con el nuevo valor. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras saludos. Pero si los labels de la interfaz está asociados a dichas variables ¿no se supone que actualizando las variables, automaticamente se actualizan los labels? Porque como están dentro del "main", y uso "mainloop", se supone que está asignando todo el rato el valor de las variables a los labels. ¿Por qué no es asi?

Comment: Usas `mainloop` sobre el objeto `tkinter`, me parece debes usarlo sobre el objeto `root`, es decir: `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Eso que dices solo aplica a las variables de control (StringVar, Intvar, etc). Tienes que crear esas variables de control y asociarlas a los Labels con el argumento textvariable, en lugar de usar atributos o variables globales.

Comment: @DanteS. muchísimas gracias, es justamente la solución que estaba buscando. Para el caso de imágenes, ¿sabes cómo hacerlo?

Comment: De nada c: Las imagenes no hay forma de guardarlas en una variable de control. Pero puedes cambiarla haciendo `label.config(image=imagen)`